# In Kaggle, where can I store common code to be imported into multiple Notebooks?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, python-import, kaggle

I am working on the Kaggle HuBMAP competition.   My application consists of several components -- Preprocessing, Training, Prediction and Scoring -- and there is common code that is used by more than one component.   Currently, I put multiple copies of the common code in the Notebooks for each of the components, but I'd like to maintain one copy of the common code that I can `import` into my application components.

My question is:   Where do I store that common code so that it can be imported?   Does it go in a separate DataSet?   Or a separate Notebook?   How do I store it?   How do I import it?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out how to do it:

1. Create a file like `common_code.py` to hold the code you want to import in Kaggle
2. Create a Kaggle DataSet like `CommonCode` and upload `common_code.py` to it
3. In the Notebook where you want to import the common code add the DataSet `CommonCode`
4. At the top of your Notebook, add the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( "/kaggle/input/CommonCode" )
```

Then, at any subsequent point in the Notebook you can say

```
from common_code import *
```

While this shows an example of a single import-able file, you can use it for any number of files, and you can update the DataSet for additions or revisions.